# Boot menu doesn't show up after installing Windows 7

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, windows-7, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my shiny new ASRock Vison 3D with no apparent problems. Still I need some Windows-only software from time to time and went on installing Win7 afterwards. Now Win7 happily boots but apparently has not bothered with creating a boot menu...

I assume that using a Ubuntu 10.10 Live-CD there should be a way to create a

Answer (score 3):

Always install Ubuntu **after** installing windows as Windows tends to overwrite the Bootloader thus preventing you from booting into ubuntu. However you can solve this by following the instructions given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

The link describes ways to recover your ubuntu by

- By installing **EasyBCD** on windows which allows to boot into multiple operating systems, including Ubuntu Linux.
- Recovery Using the Ubuntu Alternate/Install CD
- Recovery Using the Unofficial "Super Grub Disk"

This is an official link from the ubuntu wiki...so should be trustworthy and reliable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the pointer.. I'll try it out tomorrow and accept your answer in case of success (which I expect)